# How to use jQuery to pass value into coffescript ActionCable

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails, coffeescript, actioncable

I am trying to create dynamic channels for users to chat in, but I am unable to pass the `room_id` into the `App.cable.subscriptions.create` call that is in the `room.coffee` file. Any help in clarifying why I cannot use jQuery to get the value is extremely helpful.

This is what I receive back in the console:

```
RoomChannel is transmitting the subscription confirmation
RoomChannel is streaming from room__channel
```

**RoomsController**

```
class RoomsController < ApplicationController
  before_action :authenticate_user!

  def show
    other_user = User.find(params[:id])
    title = [other_user.id.to_s, current_user.id.to_s].sort!.join("-")
    @room = Room.where(title: title).first
    if @room.nil?
      @room = Room.create! title: title
    else
      @messages = Message.where(room_id: @room[:id])
    end
  end

end
```

**show.html.erb**

```
<h1>Chat Room</h1>
<div id="messages">
  <% if @messages.blank? %>
    <div id="no_messages_yet">
      <p>No messages yet...</p>
    </div>
  <% else %>
      <%= render @messages %>
  <% end %>
</div>
<form>
  <label>Say something:</label><br>
  <input type="text" data-behavior="room_speaker">
  <input type="hidden" value="<%= @room[:id] %>" id="room_id">
  <input type="hidden" value="<%= current_user[:id] %>" id="user_id">
</form>
```

**views/messages/_message.html.erb**

```
<div class="message">
  <p><%= message.content %></p>
</div>
```

**room.coffee**

```
$(document).ready ->
  room_id = $("#room_id").val()
  console.log(room_id)
  // => 1
  // When I try and pass 'room_id' as the value for room_id:, I get an error stating the variable is not recognized.
App.room = App.cable.subscriptions.create {channel: "RoomChannel", room_id: $('#room_id').val()},
  connected: ->
    # Called when the subscription is ready for use on the server

  disconnected: ->
    # Called when the subscription has been terminated by the server

  received: (data) ->
    $('#messages').append data['message']
    # Called when there's incoming data on the websocket for this channel

  speak: (message, room_id, user_id) ->
    @perform 'speak', message: message, room_id: room_id, user_id: user_id

$(document).on 'keypress', '[data-behavior~=room_speaker]', (event) ->
  if event.keyCode is 13 # return = send
    App.room.speak event.target.value, $('#room_id').val(), $('#user_id').val()
    event.target.value = ""
    event.preventDefault()
```

**RoomChannel**

```
class RoomChannel < ApplicationCable::Channel
  def subscribed
    stream_from "room_#{params[:room_id]}_channel"
  end

  def unsubscribed
    # Any cleanup needed when channel is unsubscribed
  end

  def speak(data)
    m = Message.new
    m.user_id = data["user_id"]
    m.room_id = data["room_id"]
    m.content = data["message"]
    m.save!
  end
end
```

**message.rb**

```
class Message < ApplicationRecord
  after_create_commit { MessageBroadcastJob.perform_later self }
end
```

**jobs/message_broadcast_job.rb**

```
class MessageBroadcastJob < ApplicationJob
  queue_as :default

  def perform(message)
    ActionCable.server.broadcast "room_#{message.room_id}_channel", message: render_message(message)
  end

  private
  def render_message(message)
    ApplicationController.renderer.render(partial: 'messages/message', locals: { message: message })
  end
end
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Place the functionality inside the `$(document).ready` call. Remember coffeescript is very touchy when it comes to indentation and whitespace.

```
$(document).ready ->
  room_id = $('#room_id').val()
  App.room = App.cable.subscriptions.create {channel: "RoomChannel", room_id: room_id},

    connected: ->
      # Called when the subscription is ready for use on the server

    disconnected: ->
      # Called when the subscription has been terminated by the server

    received: (data) ->
      $('#messages').append data['message']
      # Called when there's incoming data on the websocket for this channel

    speak: (message, room_id, user_id) ->
      @perform 'speak', message: message, room_id: room_id, user_id: user_id

$(document).on 'keypress', '[data-behavior~=room_speaker]', (event) ->
  if event.keyCode is 13 # return = send
    App.room.speak event.target.value, $('#room_id').val(), $('#user_id').val()
    event.target.value = ""
    event.preventDefault()
```

Answer (score 0):

Easiest way would be pass the value into HTML as data attribute. And read that back from CoffeeScript with jQuery.

You can add it to `messages` div or the form. Something like this:

```
<div id="messages" data-room-id="<%= params[:id] %>">
```

And in JavaScript, read it with:

```
$('#messages').data('room-id')
```

In vanilla JavaScript:

```
document.getElementById('messages').dataset.roomId
```

Comment: Thank you for your help but unfortunately no jQuery calls are working for that particular part of the code.

Comment: I've added vanilla JS version. Please check.

Comment: That threw an error: `Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'dataset' of null`

Comment: You should place the JS in footer or in a `document.ready` event. Otherwise the HTML will render after the JS and it'll cause error.

Comment: I actually tried doing that as well with both your solution and mine but it gives an error: `Uncaught ReferenceError: room_id is not defined` when I try to pass in the variable with the value. I am able to see the value and console.log it before the `App.room = App.cable.subscriptions.create` call is made, but cannot pass in the variable as a param.